# Lucene Scoring function

Tags: java, twitter, lucene

I am working on a system that indexes and search for tweet in an Index,each tweet has a field that defines its social importance ( social value ) , I want to add this value to the similarity score so I can rank the documents by combining their social value and their score toward the query.

For example , my scoring function will be like

```
Final Score = QueryScore + Social score ( which is a float that I already calculated)
```

So how can I achieve this ?

I'm using lucene-5.5.0

```
package Lucene;


import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;

public class SearchFiles {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{

            Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\JUGURTHA\\Desktop\\boulot\\index");
            Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(path);
            DirectoryReader ireader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
            IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);
            StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
            //get each token            
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("text", analyzer);
            Query query = parser.parse("Love");
            ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.search(query, null, 20).scoreDocs;
            for (int i = 0; i <  hits.length; i++){
                Document hitDoc = isearcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
                System.out.println("Tweet " + i + " : " + hitDoc.get("text"));
                System.out.println("created_at: " + hitDoc.get("date"));
                System.out.println("id: " + hitDoc.get("id"));
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();

            }


        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already solved the problem, I used the class CustomScoreProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get the work done , I used the class CustomScoreProvider , and got the result I wanted

```
class CustomizedScoreProvider extends CustomScoreProvider {

    public CustomizedScoreProvider(LeafReaderContext reader) {
            super(reader);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    public  float customScore(int doc, float subQueryScore,float valSrcScores[]){

     try {

         subQueryScore+=4; // I only added this for testing , 
     } catch(Exception e) { 
         e.printStackTrace();
            }
    return subQueryScore;
             }
    }

class CustomizedScoreQuery extends CustomScoreQuery{


public CustomizedScoreQuery(Query subQuery,IndexReader ireader) {
        super(subQuery);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
public CustomizedScoreProvider getCustomScoreProvider (LeafReaderContext reader){
    CustomizedScoreProvider i=new CustomizedScoreProvider(reader);
     return (i);
}
}
```